# Beautifulsoup & mechanize crawler won't work

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize, urllib

I'm trying to go to a website and scrape all the links that include the host websites url. when I run the code with the print statement in the if statement uncommented, I get a list of scraped urls from the host website including their paths but when I put the print statement as a comment I just get 'error' from my try.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse
import mechanize

url = "http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.html"
br = mechanize.Browser()
urls = [url]
visited = [url]

while len(urls)>0:
    try:
        br.open(urls[0])
        urls.pop(0)
        for link in br.links():
            newurl = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url,link.url)
            b1 = urlparse.urlparse(newurl).hostname
            b2 = urlparse.urlparse(newurl).path
            newurl = "http://"+b1+b2

            if newurl not in visited and urlparse.urlparse(url).hostname in newurl:
                urls.append(newurl)
                visited.append(newurl)
                #print newurl
    except:
        print "error"
        urls.pop(0)
print visited
```

Comment: Instead of `print "error"` try `traceback.print_exc` which will tell you what error actually occured, see https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. I got the following traceback

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "linkcrawler.py", line 21, in <module>
        newurl = "http://"+b1+b2
    TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Comment: `b1` is None when `newurl` is an empty string or doesn't contain a hostname. This could happen if the link is an anchor (has no base url) like `<a href="#anchor">Go To Anchor</a>`.